# Resolving PyDev Unresolved imports regarding numpy & sklearn

Tags: numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, pydev, kaggle

I've nearly everything I can find to resolve these Unresolved imports. Here is what I am trying to import:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from numpy import genfromtxt, savetxt
```

In eclipse on Mac OS X Lion running PyDev I get the following errors;

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Unresolved import: genfromtxt   makeSubmission.py   /BioResponse/src    line 1  PyDev Problem
Unresolved import: RandomForestClassifier   makeSubmission.py   /BioResponse/src    line 0  PyDev Problem
Unresolved import: savetxt  makeSubmission.py   /BioResponse/src    line 1  PyDev Problem
```

Note this is for setting up [Kaggle](http://www.kaggle.com/wiki/GettingStartedWithPythonForDataScience).

The thing I dont get is that when I am in terminal and type the following commands, everything seems ok (I don't see any visible errors):

```
$python
Python 2.7.3 (v2.7.3:70274d53c1dd, Apr  9 2012, 20:52:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from numpy import savetxt
>>>
```

Please try to explain in detailed steps if you know a possible solution. I'm new to Macs and PyDev

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you have 2 python interpreters installed on your system and the one used by PyDev is not the one where numpy is installed.

Type `which python` in a terminal to know the path of the python installed in your `PATH` where numpy is installed and then go to the PyDev preference menu to know which python is configured for PyDev.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out numpy was installed for 2.6 and not 2.7!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be to add your /Library/Python/2.x/site-packages folder to System Libs in the Eclipse Preferences under 'PyDev -> Interpreter Python -> Libraries'.

Answer (score 0):

Based on David's solution be sure the proper typing. For me (in Eclipse):
Window -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Interpreters -> Python Interpreter -> (Chose the version on the top) -> Libraries -> And here there was a typo:

C:\Python35\lib\site-packages

instead of

C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages